# Do latest windows insider preview builds work in vmware workstation 12?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, windows-insider

I need to install and use Windows Insider running as a guest in vmware. I have an  available license for vmware workstation 12, which appears to be the maintenance release branch. Will these two work with each other?

There are conflicting reports. First, vmware [says](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&details=1&partner=110&operatingSystems=204&productNames=3&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc&testConfig=16) that Windows 10 is a supported Guest OS on Workstation 12 and 12.5. No mention of Windows Insider Preview builds, though. But the workstation 14 [release notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14/rn/workstation-14-release-notes.html) say that Windows 10 Creators Update is now supported as a guest.

If Creators Update is only supported as a guest in vmware workstation 14+, how can vmware claim that Windows 10 will run with the older workstation 12 branch?

I suspect that Windows Insider Previews will not work with workstation 12 and don't want to lose a bunch of hours trying to make it work (I am new to both vmware and windows). But if you know that they DO work together, let me know, and I won't have to buy another vmware license!

Comment: It takes at most, 20 minutes, to install Windows on a virtual machine.  As for how VMWare Workstation 12 supports Windows 10, it supports, previous builds specifically.  Doesn’t mean future builds can’t be used.

Comment: @Ramhound if you make a virtual hard disk and create a Windows-to-go, it'll take only 10 min (depends on hardware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Windows 10 Insider Preview guest on VMWare Workstation 12 Player. Host OS is Windows 10 Pro 1803 64 bit . Installer I used was VMware-player-12.5.9-7535481.exe. Insider installed & runs fine and has updated itself 4 times, currently running Build 18204 (19H1- Skip Ahead) 64 bit. VMWare Tools version 10.1.6 build 5214329 is installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have VMWare Workstation, I cant say with 100% certainty.  However, there is no reason it shouldnt work.  Any x86 or x64 OS should work inside VMWare Workstation.  Even if the VMware tools software is not available, it should still work.  It could very well be that they do not test the Insider builds, as they are not considered full releases.  I do not believe you should have any issues running them.